# How to check if a specific time falls in between 2 times in Excel?

Tags: excel, time, excel-formula

I used this formula `IF(AND(C2>=MIN(A2:B2),C2<=MAX(A2:B2)),"Within Shift","Post Shift")`. In the image attached the shift is 5pm to 2am, but the comments comes as post shift. Since Excel consider time as 24 hrs the comment comes out as "Post Shift" is there a way to fix this? Please help.

[image: Attached image]

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution:

```
=IF(AND(IF(C2>=A2,C2,C2+1)<=IF(B2>=A2, B2, B2+1)), "Within Shift", "Post Shift")
```

The underlying assumption is that column C is always greater than column A.

Offline time could either be prior the start of shift or after the end of shift. Example: Assuming start of shift 07:00 AM and end of shift 04:00 PM and off time at 02:00 AM. We can either interpret 02:00 AM to be prior to 07:00 AM or to he next day after 04:00 PM. There is no way to solve the ambiguity. The safest bet is to assume the off time is always after the start of shift. As such, since 02:00 AM < 07:00 AM, we add 1 day and compare the result to the end of shift. Same applies to end of shift, if it seems to be prior to start of shift, we add 1 day to it prior to comparison.

Comment: Hi Tarik, thank you responding so promptly, really appreciate it, but i am not able to understand what you are trying to say could you elaborate a little more if you don't mind.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply I understand what you mean. I have another clarification regarding something similar, if you can please help me out with the. 
PFB the link to my other query.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63100485/how-to-check-if-a-2-specific-time-falls-in-between-2-times-shifts-in-excel

Answer (score 1):

Your formula is based on the idea that both times are within the same day, which is not true in the last case (the shift end time is on the next day).

In order to solve this, it might be useful to realise that datetime values in Excel are based on the idea that one day is equal to the value 1.

So, in case B2 is smaller than A2, you might need to replace the usage of B2 by the usage of B2+1 (the same time, but the next day), so your formula becomes something like (multiline for readability purposes):

```
=IF(A2<B2,
    <use your formula, based on B2>,
    <use your formula, based on B2+1>)
```

The second part, about using your formula, based on B2+1, this means something like:

```
IF(AND(C2>=MIN(A2:B2+1),C2<=MAX(A2:B2+1)),
   "Within Shift",
   "Post Shift")
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response @Dominique. I have another clarification regarding something similar, if you can please help me out with the. PFB the link to my other query.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63100485/how-to-check-if-a-2-specific-time-falls-in-between-2-times-shifts-in-excel

Comment: Will look at it and see what I can do.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tarik. Please do let me know if you are able to get something about the query.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different approach to the existing answers:

```
=IF(MOD(1+C2-A2,1)=MIN(MOD(1+C2-A2,1), MOD(1+C2-B2,1)), "Within Shift", "Post Shift")
```

Basically, it takes the "target" time (Shift End or Offline Time), adds 24 hours (`1` day), *subtracts* the Shift Start Time, and fits it inside a day (i.e. if the result is over 24 hours, keep subtracting 24 hours until the time is less than a day)

This will give you either the length of their shift, or how long they were online (depending on which is the "target time").

We then use `MIN` to find out which of these two times were shorter, and then compare that to the Time Spent Online.  If they are the same, then they went offline within their shift.  If they are different, then they went offline after their shift.

Note  that if they go offline *exactly* at shift-end, this will be counted as "Within Shift".  If you want this to be "Post Shift", then change the `MIN` to `MAX`, and swap the two labels

Comment: Thank you so much for the prompt reply @Chronocidal . Your formula worked.

Comment: I have another clarification regarding something similar, if you can please help me out with the. PFB the link to my other query. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63100485/how-to-check-if-a-2-specific-time-falls-in-between-2-times-shifts-in-excel